# large ellipse draws as a diamond

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

When we run this code:

```
import pygame
w=2560
h=1440  
print(w*h)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, pygame.Color(255,255,255), screen.get_rect())
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(.25)
```

we get this "ellipse":
[image: Ceci n'est pas un ellipse]

It seems to be a function of total area of the ellipse or something? As we shrink it down, it starts to work correctly again - but if we increase the other dimension (say, shrink height and increase width), it eventually breaks again. It looks like if it's more than about 3.4M pixels it breaks or something, but I haven't narrowed it down, and not totally sure it's area that's related to the problem.

Comment: Confirmed. Seems to be a pygame bug.

Comment: I've reported it on the pygame github. The main pygame.draw guy sees it as a bug and thinks he's got the solution.

Comment: [Fix drawing of big ellipses #2880](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/2880)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in pagame and reported on in the pygame github repository: [Fix drawing of big ellipses #2880](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/2880)